# Is this good practice to change build files directly in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular7

I have some scenario to modify build files after deployment. Is this good practice to change manually?

Comment: Can you describe your scenario please? Build output is transpiled and minified, I don't think it's worth the effort. I don't understand what you need to do post-build that can't be done pre-build?

Comment: We are using one docker image to manage Dev, staging and production. So after ng build --prod we have change API base url based on the server environment.

Comment: there's a lot of reasons to not do it, the framework is prepared to build with AOT or not for example, if you change values after that build, the angular framework can make some issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, I would make build again and then deploy it. In your case if you do not have time to do all of this and you are sure your changes won't break it then go ahead.

Comment: Rephrase my question. Is it good practice to change API base url after build has been done?

Comment: honestly not. I wouldn't suggest ever to do this.

Answer (score 3):

As per the discussion in the comments, what you want to do is to have different configurations for different environments, there are lots of ways to accomplish this. A built in angular cli way is to use different [build configurations](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#alternate-build-configurations). Build configurations have a file replacements option that replaces a file you specify with different variants of it.

In the default scaffold project you can see this pattern with the `environments/environment.ts` file. You will see a production variant of it with the name `environment.prod.ts` To have a different api url for production all you have to do is to add the production api url to that file and the development api url to `environment.ts` For staging, you will have to create a build configuration with a file replacement called `environment.staging.ts`

The configuration in `angular.json` would look like this,

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": ".../environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": ".../environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
               ]
              ...
              "staging": {
               "fileReplacements": [
                 {
                   "replace": ".../environments/environment.ts",
                   "with": ".../environments/environment.staging.ts"
                  }
                ],
  }
```

Make sure you always import the api base url from `environment.ts` and not any of the variants. `ng build --configuration staging` will do the replacement for you.